# How to add "SKU" and "Product Name" to sales order grid?

Tags: magento-enterprise, sales, order-grid

I am trying to add "sku" and "product name" to sales order grid with filtering.

I have created my joins but the columns are empty and I'm not sure what I have done incorrectly here...

Trying to get collection from sales/flat_order_item

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoi' => 'sales_flat_order_item'),
        'sfoi.parent_id=main_table.entity_id', array('sfoi.sku',
        'sfoi.name'));

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

And add to the grid

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('sku', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Sku'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter_index' => 'sfoi.sku',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product Name'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter_index' => 'sfoi.name',
    ));
}
```

Can anyone see what I have done wrong here please..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('sku', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Sku'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'index' => 'sfoi.sku',
        'filter_index' => 'sfoi.sku',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product Name'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'index' => 'sfoi.name',
         'filter_index' => 'sfoi.name',
    ));
}
```

**you haven't assign index to column**

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  Create the Renderer directory under `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order`

Step 2:
Create a Block File in `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Renderer/Red.php` (You can use any name)

```
<?php


class
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Red extends
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract

    {
      public function render(Varien_Object $row)

       {

         //$value = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());



        $order_id=$row->getData('increment_id');

        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementID($order_id);

        $items = $order->getAllItems();

        // print_r($items);exit();

            foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)

                {

                if($item->getSku())

                    {

                    $sku[] = $item->getSku();

                    }

                }

                if(count($sku))

                    {

                    $skutext = implode(',',$sku);

                    }

            $conbinetext=$skutext;

            return $conbinetext;

        }

    }



?>
```

Step 3: Add the Below Code in `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php`

```
$this->addColumn('Shopby',


  array(


  'header'=>Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Sku'),

  'index' => 'shopby',

  'filter'=> false,


  'sortable'=>false,

  'renderer'=> 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Red',// THIS IS WHAT THIS POST IS ALL ABOUT

  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

May be help some one

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_item', 'sales_flat_order_item.order_id = main_table.entity_id', array('skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(sales_flat_order_item.sku SEPARATOR ", ")'),'names' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(sales_flat_order_item.name SEPARATOR ", ")')))->group('main_table.entity_id');

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```